# for loop enters 0% cpu hang

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, clr

I have a need to take a list of files, trim them to the directory path and return a distinct list. In some cases this may process across over five million files.

I am experiencing an issue where the core process hangs with 0% CPU usage for reasons i cannot determine.

```
var filePaths = File.ReadAllLines("list_of_files.txt");
// ...
blockSw.Restart();
int[] curCounter = new int[1];
Stopwatch groupSw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Parallel.For(0, filePaths.LongLength, i =>
  {
    //Trim the filename, if it exists, off of every
    // entry that we read out of the input file
    filePaths[i] = (Path.GetDirectoryName(filePaths[i]));
    //This can be used to safely report status
    // little hack-y, though
    lock (curCounter)
    {
        curCounter[0]++;
        if (curCounter[0] % 100000 == 0)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(curCounter[0].ToString() + " rows complete in "
                + groupSw.ElapsedMilliseconds
                + " ; total time: " + blockSw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            groupSw.Restart();
        }
    }
  }
);
blockSw.Stop();
Trace.WriteLine("Completed path truncation in " + blockSw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms.");
```

The output then looks something like this:

```
100000 rows complete in 266 ; total time: 266
200000 rows complete in 239 ; total time: 507
300000 rows complete in 843 ; total time: 1351
400000 rows complete in 1058 ; total time: 2411
...
1100000 rows complete in 3480 ; total time: 11602
1200000 rows complete in 432 ; total time: 12036
1300000 rows complete in 342 ; total time: 12379
...
4800000 rows complete in 832 ; total time: 48617
4900000 rows complete in 377 ; total time: 48996
5000000 rows complete in 2841 ; total time: 51839
5100000 rows complete in 1285 ; total time: 53126
Completed path truncation in 148124ms.
```

Notice the last two lines... 53seconds to get through everything, then the loop ends, and we sit around and wait for ~90seconds. Watching the process in TaskManager i can see it just idle at 0% CPU during this time.

Any clues as to what's going on here or where i might look for clues?

The input file that lists file paths is ~400MB, and the memory size as reported by TaskManager is about 900MB during this process. There is plenty of free physical RAM available above this amount during tests.

Taking out the in-loop status reporting makes no change in performance - we still get a ~90sec hang of 0% CPU usage at the end of the loop.

I have the same problem with a standard `for` loop instead of `Parallel.For`.

---

### Update / Solution

Thanks to Chris, Jack and Hans. With Chris' input that he wasn't able to reproduce and Hans suggestion for Break All i was able to narrow in on the problem. A little debugging further and i discovered that the actual issue is that `Path.GetDirectoryName` was the culprit. While it ran in 0-15ms on almost every file path, there were a couple of dozen paths which it took up to 2min to process. I notice that these paths all contain ~ in them. I am still not clear why it does this without using the CPU at all but it is sufficient for me to understand that it's a `Path` internal and the only way to speed it up would be to re-implement `GetDirectoryName`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in LINQPad. Maybe it's something with the tracing? EDIT: However, mine takes only ~9600ms to complete (even with a 400mb file with 51500000 rows). It's all the same file path in the file though, so maybe there's some branch prediction coming into play. But nowhere near your 53 seconds. EDITx2: or more likely, just the available system resources considering the parallel loop. `for` loop for me took ~32 seconds (still not random delay at the end though)

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and find where it is hanging?

Comment: Not the right way to ask this question.  Post the *simplest* version of the code.  When you observe the hang, use Debug + Break All and show us what the Call Stack window content looks like.  Enable unmanaged debugging and the Microsoft Symbol Server.  If you see strange named DLLs back in that call stack then you've found the primary source of this hang.

Comment: This does not achieve the stated requirement of distinct list.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, @Jack and @Hans. With Chris being unable to reproduce on a different data set and Hans' suggestion to Break All and confirm what it's actually doing i was able to confirm it is in fact some long-running `Path.GetDirectoryName` calls.

Comment: @Blam Correct. Once the paths are read and cleaned i simply select out Distinct with LINQ.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why would save duplicates only to filter later?

Comment: @Blam - The short answer is that it only takes ~3sec to filter five million rows and so the focus has been on the part which took the longest time (~2.5min total to `Path.GetDirectoryName` everything). I might take a whack at those 3sec in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As for distinct.
Might not be faster than do them all and then a single LINQ but it should be less memory.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
   String line;
   String path;
   HashSet<string> paths = HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
   // Read and process lines from the file until the end of
   // the file is reached.
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(line);
       path = Path.GetDirectoryName(line);
       if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) paths.Add(path.Trim());
   }
}
```